# How to zoom image automatically when focused while scrolling in android

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview, scrollview, zooming

[image]

I am trying to implement the above scenario described in the image, There were couple of designs like oval, star, rectangle, square and many more, when I will scroll that images, the center image should be zoom when it focused and when I scroll the images, the left images needs to be zoom out and of course right one also as described in the image.

I have tried so many example of **carousel android** but it doesn't work for me. Also tried **horizontal scrollview** but the result remains same. I have implemented this example from github, see this **https://github.com/ninchuu/android-carousel**

Please have a look to the below link what I exactly want to do,
**http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/17/**

So anybody suggest me what I should do? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been too long, but i too was trying to get the things done as you want. A big thank you to Deep Mehta who has created such a wonderful example.

You can download the full example from github link
https://github.com/DeepMehtaIPath/ImageSlider-for-Android

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful to me. Good job